# How can one create a double horizontal axis for a plot in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I need to show the values on the horizontal axis (aka abscissa, aka x-axis) converted into other units. Hence the need for a second axis.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not currently possible.  Hopefully after this summer.

Comment: +1 for the right answer, +1 for promising, +inf for ggplot2 itself !